# How dictionary is created when making dictionary-based text classifications? How values are determined?

Tags: dictionary, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I'm trying to create sentimental analysis of about 1 million twits I've collected from Twitter. I've found a lot of dictionary related to text categorization. The dictionaries I found were rated words between -4 and +4. For example,

> fan 3
>
> angry -2
>
> revenge -2
>
> bad -3
>
> calm 2
>
> celebration 3

What I wonder is how numbers are given to words. How can I sure that numbers are valid? How dictionaries are created?

Comment: This question seems to be [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it does not ask anything related to programming. It is rather a general question relating to Natural Language Processing / Sentiment Analysis. As such I would move it to [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange forum. Could you please move it there?

Answer (score 0):

The example you have provided appears to be (subjectively) rating the words based on their "positive/negative" meaning. So the following tweet "That was a bad celebration; I am an angry fan." would score a +1 whereas "I am a fan of that celebration!" would score a +6.

The final sum for any tweet can then be used in a strategy to do *something*. You could send bags of candy to anyone that tweets -10 or below in hopes of cheering them up. You could persist a tweet with a score of +50 or higher so that it shows to more people.

It's all an analysis game and there are no "right answers" when it comes to assigning subjective numbers to words until you provide a specific intent of what you wish to do with the resultant data.